# Time Machine error in server.app 10.8

Tags: macos, time-machine, osx-server

I currently have a Mac Mini with 10.8 and server.app 2.2 installed.  The server is currently only set up with File Sharing and Time Machine services running.  It is handing out network Time Machine volumes to users on our network.

Recently, I keep running into this error whenever trying to get the Time Machine service in server.app.

```
Mar 11 09:20:08 retouch.roundhouseagency.com servermgrd[1669]: [1669] error in getAndLockContext: flock(servermgr_timemachine) FATAL time out
Mar 11 09:20:08 retouch.roundhouseagency.com servermgrd[1669]: [1669] process will force-quit to avoid deadlock
Mar 11 09:20:08 retouch.roundhouseagency.com servermgrd[1669]: outstanding requests are: (
        Module = "servermgr_timemachine";
        Module = "servermgr_timemachine";
        Module = "servermgr_timemachine";
        Module = "servermgr_timemachine";
        Module = "servermgr_timemachine";
Mar 11 09:20:08 retouch com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.servermgrd[1669]): Exited with code: 1
```

The server.app stops responding and eventually throws an error message.  I went through this thread [How to fix hanging Server Admin, log shows servermgrd error in getAndLockContext: flock(servermgr_info) FATAL time out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54636/how-to-fix-hanging-server-admin-log-shows-servermgrd-error-in-getandlockcontext) as it was the closest to the error I'm having.  Everything in that thread points to a DNS error, but I haven't found any issues with the DNS record so far.

Anyone have any insight as to what the cause may be?

Comment: dumb question: have you restarted the Mac Server yet?

Comment: I did, sadly.  No joy.  The odd thing was that I restarted the server once, and the problem seemed to go away.  For about half an hour, I could get into the Time Machine Settings before the issue came back.  But the second time I restarted, I've been unable to get into the Time Machine settings at all, even directly after the restart.

Comment: My next suggestion is to switch off the Time Machine service and then restart it again. This will re-write some settings in your /Library folder. The suggestions I have beyond that are more intrusive in nature.

Comment: Tried that earlier, but noticed that now my Time Machine shares need to be recreated.  I'm new to 10.8 Server and haven't been happy with the features and interface thus far.  I'm going to explore some other Mac enterprise backup solutions, I think I may be trying to shoehorn Time Machine into a role that doesn't really fit.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Personally I think CrashPlan Pro is worth a look. It's way more customizable than Time Machine. It works over the internet very well. And it's a pretty cheap solution all things considered.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!  CrashPlan is something we've done some cursory investigation about, but the recurring subscription costs will be steep compared to the free cost of Time Machine.  Do you have any other recommendations for enterprise backup solutions that have a one-time fee?  I'm trying out Retrospect right now, but would love to know what else is highly recommended out there.  I've really only run into a lot of consumer/small business solutions (Carbon Copy Cloner, SuperDuper, etc.) that don't fit our needs.